# Public member value of a class is not changing

Tags: c++, class, setter

I have a class called "Turns", which has all its members in public. Until now, I hadn't edited the values of the members of this class (only read), but I have changed values of other classes in other headers without problem. The issue is that now I want to change a value and it seems not to work regardless how I try.

Turns.h

```
#ifndef TURNS_H
#define TURNS_H

#include "Constants.h"
using namespace Constants;

#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "utilities.h"

class Turns
{
public: 
    Turns();
    void insertk(double val, int i);

    int k[5]; // K denotes the fixed radius for R turns
    double K[4];
    string TPT; // F for fly-by turns. R for fix turns.
    int headings[5]; // Measured from Arrival Airport Threshold
    static const int hdgSIZE=5;
    double thr2wpt[4]; // Measured from Arrival Airport Threshold
    int phi_max[4];
    double turnrate_max[4];
    double scale;
    double Deltachig[4]; // Angle changed
    double phi_end[4]; // Estimated phi at the end of the turn
    double turnrate[4];
    int iend[4]; // Starting distance
};

#endif
```

Turns.cpp

```
#include "Turns.h"

Turns::Turns()
{
    k[0]=0; k[1]=0; k[2]=0; k[3]=0; k[4]=0;
    TPT="FFFFF";
    headings[0]=35; headings[1]=60; headings[2]=80; headings[3]=50; headings[4]=40;
    thr2wpt[0]=-50*nm2m; thr2wpt[1]=-150*nm2m; thr2wpt[2]=-350*nm2m;   thr2wpt[3]=-500*nm2m;
    phi_max[0]=16; phi_max[1]=23; phi_max[2]=22; phi_max[3]=1;
    turnrate_max[0]=1.5; turnrate_max[1]=3.0; turnrate_max[2]=3.0; turnrate_max[3]=3.0;
    scale=1.5;

    // We finish to fill
    for(int n=0; n<(sizeof(headings)/sizeof(headings[0])-1); n++)
    {
        K[n]=0;
        Deltachig[n]=headings[n+1]-headings[n];
        if(abs(Deltachig[n])>180)
            Deltachig[n]=Deltachig[n]-360*sign(Deltachig[n]);
        phi_max[n]=sign(Deltachig[n])*phi_max[n];
        phi_end[n]=phi_max[n]/scale;
        turnrate[n]=sign(Deltachig[n])*turnrate_max[n];
        iend[n]=0;
    }
}

void Turns::insertk(double val, int i)
{
    this->k[i]=val;
}
```

The part which is not working is the function "insertk". For instance, in the main I have val=0.00023 and i=0 and the value of "k" does not change. In the main (simplified since it is a part of a big program) I have:

```
Turns * tns;
tns=new Turns();
tns->insertk(0.00023, 0);
```

If I try to replace directly the value (Which should work since the member is public), the result is the same:

```
tns->k[0]=0.00023
```

*PS: I know the members should be protected, but I read them a lot and I want to know why the value of "k" does not change.*

Comment: How do you determine whether it changed or not? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: You have an array of *integers* named `k` and an array of doubles named `K`. Don't you mix those two?

Comment: Well I read it while executing (in the programming environment). But it does not change because after the setter I have a division with k[0] and it cannot be done since it is a division by 0 (which is the initial value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your `k` array is declared as an array of integers. If you assign `0.00023` to an integer it will get rounded (truncated) to `0`. So, this would appear as if the value of `k[0]` did not change. It was zero originally, it remained zero after assignment. Yet, the assignment has been carried out.

Why are you trying to assign `0.00023` to an integer? Weren't you supposed to use your `K` array instead, which is declared as an array of doubles? In any case, having two different data members named `k` and `K` in your class is not a good idea at all, unless you have some very compelling reason to name them like that.

Comment: Not rounded, but *truncated*.

Comment: Yeah, my error. "k" should be a double. My Lord... Thanks anyway.